# Business logic with Biztalk

Tags: c#, biztalk

The question is where is the best place to put your buisness logic: is it inside `biztalk` orchestartions or in an outside component like `libraries`?

I suppose with certain amount of afford you can achieve the same functionality in either way, But what are the benefits of having logic siting in either of the places?

Case 1:

[image]

Case 2:

[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Share those with us then you can get some productive feedback. Otherwise you will find lot of document about best practices.

Comment: @Nazmul tiried anything, really? I'm not asking for piece of code, but for an advice from expirinced people who had a chance to deal with either of the techics and can share their thoughts. What do i need to share here exactly?

Comment: There are many many ways to handle business logic in BizTalk (in SQL, in Map, in BRE, in custom .NET library, hard coded in orchestration, in custom pipeline component).  How often might the logic change?  Who would have to change it?  What impact would changes have on other parts of the process?  If you have a more concrete example it be more suitable and avoid getting closed as too broad.

Comment: Case #2 is the correct Patter to start a BizTalk app design.  Though reusing existing components is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BizTalk is a powerful tool but like all it can be used badly...try reading here to get you started
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12854/Explaining-the-BizTalk-Architecture-to-your-Grandm

> **Orchestrations**
>
> Orchestrations are processes that are defined in the Business Process Execution Language (BPEL). This could be something like, say: if quantity is greater than threshold, apply discount, else standard discount. At this stage, you can also change the format of the message using Transformation Maps, or you can call some other web service to do an operation like credit card verification. This is like our example in which we have the customs inspection process and checking with the bank if the excise payment is cleared.
>
> **Business Rules Engine**
>
> Business Rules Engine is used by BizTalk to load the current policies which are a collection of Rules from the Orchestration. These rules are kept separately as these could change from time to time. In our example above, this would be something like, during Olympics there could be certain relaxations in guidelines or certain promotions in effect. These change from time to time, and they are kept separate. This is the idea behind the Rule Store in BizTalk.
>
> [image]